# c# mongodb projection builder through iteration

Tags: c#, mongodb

My goal is to build a projection definition from the Field List type.  I would like to achieve this dynamically.  It doesn't work when I do this,

```
var projectionBuilder = Builders<Article>.Projection;
foreach (var field in requestDetails.Fields)
{
  projectionBuilder.Include(field);
}
await _collection.Find<Entity>(_ => true).Project<Entity>(projectionBuilder.Exclude("_id")).Limit(10).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
var projectionDefinition = Builders<DBInfo>.Projection.Include(_ => _.count);
projectionDefinition = projectionDefinition.Include(_ => _.info.x);
projectionDefinition = projectionDefinition.Include("type"); // You can also use text
```

Full example here

https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/02%20-%20Intermediate/DynamicQuery.cs